# Prove that $\lim_{n=1}^\infty(\prod\limits_{k = 0}^n1+x_k)$ exists if and only if $\lim_{n=1}^\infty(\sum_{k=1}^n x_k)$ exists

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

From the title. $(x_n)$ is a sequence of positive real numbers.  I'm tempted to try to relate the second limit to e^x, so that the result follows from the fact that $e^x\ge x+1$ for all $x$ bigger than $0$. But am unsure how it would work.

Comment: Please replace every `\lim_{n=1}^\infty` by `\lim_{n\to\infty}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_k<\prod_{k=1}^{n}(1+x_k)< \prod_{k=1}^{n}e^{x_k}=\exp\mathopen{}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_k\right)\mathclose{}\text{.}$$
So if the product converges, the left inequality implies that so does the sum. And if the sum converges, then the right inequality implies that so does the product.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Take the logarithm of the former, and use the [Mercator series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_series).

Comment: Ok, so the former becomes a double sum over ((-1)^n)/n *x^n. I fail to see how that helps.

Comment: @TomasSmith: $\ln(1+t)\simeq t$. What do you know about alternating series ?

Comment: Oh, right, thank you.